# debug.log file is not created, what is the alternative?

Tags: linux, wordpress, server, hosting, httpd.conf

/etc/httpd/vhost.d/domainname

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName domain_name.com
  ServerAlias www.domain_name.com

  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
  DocumentRoot /data/www/domain_name

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domain_name-error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domain_name-access.log combined

  Protocols h2 http/1.1

  RedirectMatch 404 /\\.(svn|git|gitignore|hg|bzr|cvs)(/|$)

  <Directory /data/www/domain_name>
    AllowOverride All
    Options All -Indexes
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

I am a server admin, my developers wants debug.log to be created in wp-content which seems to be blocked by hosting provider.

but the file /var/log/httpd/domain_name-error.log seems to be logging fine, is this file same as debug.log or are they log different errors?

if they are different, is there any alternative, i can create debug.log for this wordpress site?

I have also tried with .htaccess file

```
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
```

which  is also throwing 500 internal server error, seems that

Comment: You can tell WP where to put the debug log in config so maybe you could put it in that same directory as the other log file you mentioned. Maybe permissions are lax enough to allow that. However, if you're using shared hosting, then the host may have made it impossible to log using default WP debug methods. Because debug logs can grow quite enormous in very little time, they tend to disallow it to save space. I think your only options are to ask your web host if you can log debug events and how to do it. If they won't allow it then your only option may be to move to a host that does.

Comment: got your point.